# Queue stops working after quiting - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am a newbie with laravel, and I am implementing email verification system  with queue in laravel.

What happening is, when I execute `php artisan queue:work` it works fine, when it needs to triggers, but when I quit the queue and re-execute, it doesn't trigger anymore.

I tried `php artisan queue:restart`, but it didn't do the trick.

What could be causing this please?

Answer (score 1):

Queue will only work as long as `queue:work` is still running or executing in console. Any  jobs fired after this  has stopped will not be executed. You get to see your jobs in the database if you are using database driver as your queue driver . I use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to keep `queue:work` running at the backround

Comment: The only way i can get it working again is to restart my machine. How can i get it working with supervisor?

Comment: yes but i am using database driver as my queue driver

Comment: Since you are using database, you can refire them  with php artisan queue:retry. Your jobs should be in jobs table in the database